# Laravel 5 mobile app login via token authentication

Tags: laravel-5, access-token

Is there any library or tutorial on token authentication compatible for Laravel 5? I'm working on a client mobile application and as far as I know, login is usually made via token auth, but surprisingly there are absolutely no results on the subject. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$fb = new Facebook\Facebook([
      'app_id' => config('services.facebook.app_id'),
      'app_secret' => config('services.facebook.app_secret'),
      'default_graph_version' => config('services.facebook.api_version'),
    ]);

    try {
        $response = $fb->get('/me?fields=id,name,email,gender', $request->input('facebook_access_token'));
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
        // When Graph returns an error
        //echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        //exit;

        return $this->setStatusCode(403)->respondWithError('Not Authorized!');
    } catch (Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
        // When validation fails or other local issues
        //echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
        //exit;

        return $this->setStatusCode(500)->respondWithError('Backend Error!');
    }

    $facebookUser = $response->getGraphUser();
```